# Load Balancer Passing Message via TCP and using TLS protocol

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, load-balancing, distributed

I am writing an application where in we are passing message via TCP layers directly using SSLSocket classes in Java (secure socket connection)

Now we want to use a Load Balancer receiving and Passing Message to the end/real servers via TCP layer messaging only. We do not wish to use a HTTPS protocol for this communication.

We wish to send a TCP encrypted message (SSL secure socket connection) to load balancer and want the load balancer to directly send this message to the real/end server without decrypting the message receive via TCP message directly, and the message will be decrypted at the end/real server after receiving the same from Load Balancer to perform some action.

Which know load balancer will help me achieve this ?

Any links, documentation or methodology to implement this will be of great help.

Which load balancer will be usefull and meeting this requirement.

Kindly let me know in case of any clarification or any information is needed on the same.

Thanks
Cheers.!!!!

Comment: I checked out  TCP load balancing with Nginx. Is it doing what I wanted to ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

haproxy is a very good bet.
However to achieve stickiness between the LB and the various backends, some kinds of flags need to be involved (source IP/port, SSL Session ID …).
Have a look at http://blog.haproxy.com/loadbalancing-faq/#summary
Layer 4 LB is what you want.

Comment: thanks , i'll have a go and post in case I find anything relevant to ask. Also can u just suggest if it is a good choice for supporting secure TCP connections (via TLS protocol) ??? Also it states that it does not require any intellegence. So will it consider the CPU usage, etc, parameters while redirecting (link : http://blog.haproxy.com/2011/07/29/layer-4-load-balancing-tunnel-mode/)?

Comment: It's a good choice for TLS. Again however, if your backend application is statefull, you will need to stick to something (say source ip/port) to achieve session stickiness without deciphering the payload.

Comment: Hi iga, I was facing difficulty in configuring the same, I know it is simple but it is first time for me, do you have any links or documents which explains the terms and the process so that I can understand it better. Something like a simple short summary to configure , if possible for you to provide.!!! thanks for your help.

Comment: From a default configuration file like when installing in debian, you need to declare at least one fronted and one backend.  Have a look at [some exemples](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-haproxy-and-load-balancing-concepts) found on Google.